# Does installing Wireshark via homebrew provide a graphical interface?

Tags: macos, homebrew, wireshark

I installed wireshark using homebrew with the command `brew install wireshark`. Everything seems to install fine and I can use dumpcap to capture packets but now I want to view them. Using a text editor like vi doesn't format some of the output very well due to an abundance of unreadable characters.

It looks like there should be a Wireshark.app to view the trace files with, however, I do not see how to start it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Type `brew options wireshark` to show the options provided with wireshark.

To install Wireshark with the UI :

```
brew install wireshark --with-qt
```

If you've already installed, you can use the `reinstall` command instead. This should only download the required qt dependencies.

```
brew reinstall wireshark --with-qt
```

Comment: No dice, when I try that I get ImportError: dlopen(./.libs/_giscanner.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    ./.libs/_giscanner.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't get the ImportError. It might be possible to try a clean build with the -universal option.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the pre-built Wireshark binaries from http://www.wireshark.org/download.html you get the X11 GUI built in. It calls up X11 on its own (which can take a while to start and make it appear as if Wireshark is broken).

Answer (score 0):

The new approach is to use `brew install wireshark --with-qt`.

The `--with-x` option no longer works.

More details on the switch to QT: https://blog.wireshark.org/2013/10/switching-to-qt/